# Windows 7 update stuck while downloading

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, service-pack

*In Short: On an Eee PC 1015, I am not able to update the newly installed Windows 7 system that came with that Netbook. Updates only worked in small increments, rebooting multiple times, and the SP1 does not download.*

After getting a used Asus Eee PC 1015 PED (Windows 7 Starter, 250 GB harddisk), I did this F9 Recovery offered at the boot screen. This seems to overwrite the System partition with factory install. I would not exactly call this a fresh Win7 installation as ASUS did some modifications.

- When I first connected the newly installed system and checked for updates, it said "Windows is up to date" - which is impossible. Is this suspicious? Have you ever heard of malware infecting the recovery system?

After rebooting, tens of updates were shown, but the download was stuck at "downloading .. 0 KB, 0% complete". After hours of waiting, I then shut the system dowd. The shutdown button actually promised to install updates before shutdown, and so it did.

This repeated about five times: Stuck while downloading, seems to have downloaded something, updates installed on reboot. Now all that is left is the "Windows 7 SP 1 (KB976932)" and 4 optional updates that I do not want either.

- The best guess I can make is that the service pack takes very long - three hours, at least - to download (despite its size of allegedly 61 MB) **and** that the progress meter is broken.
- Where can I get more information about the downloading process? I am relatively new to Windows, but there have to be logfiles somewhere I guess?

---

I believe these are not culprits:

- my connectivity. I can access the Web and have good bandwidth both with wired and wireless connection. I am on a reliable company network without restrictive firewall.
- ASUS Liveupdate. This wants me to install two bogus ASUS updates, I have not complied but can't believe they are necessary ("ASUSWebStorage" and "Vibe Fun Center")

Comment: I should add that the hard disk seems to move - not much more, but definitively more than usual - while "not downloading"

Comment: I assume the offline Service Pack 1 package doesn't install?  Because the one Windows Update grabs I do believe changes based on what previous updates you had installed.